# Find a program and run it through command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, directory

I want to be able to locate where the exe of a (third-party) program I remember from only its name. (say photoshop.exe) Is that possible?

Like you can call taskmrg.exe

Comment: taskmgr will only work if the application is running.  If the application is not running you will have to do a full file system search.

Comment: You can run `taskmgr.exe` from the command line because it's in a location in the system `PATH`. Photoshop probably won't be in that `PATH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this to find:

```
dir /s c:\photoshop.exe
```

..and also to run:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /a-d /s "c:\photoshop.exe"') do "%~fa"
```

Comment: That will take forever to search the entire drive for every file named `photoshop.exe`. That's a several minute long search of the drive, and a list of more than one file possibly returned, every time you run the batch file. Surely not a good solution. (Not downvoting, just commenting.)

Comment: @KenWhite  why do you contemplate down voting if your computer is too slow? Do I need to buy you a new one ? :)

Comment: I specifically said I was **NOT** downvoting, so I'm not sure why you're being rude here. It's a poor solution, but *technically* it would work. Sometimes bad ideas just happen to work, even though they're bad ideas.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm **not** rude (until now). Btw. I know about the significance of my answer. And if you know a better one, do not hesitate to put it here. The best way to solve this is imo the use of kind of a database/index application.

Comment: @KenWhite I also see the humour instead of rudeness - but sometimes text is misinterpreted.  FWIW The solution is what I would have given to the question too (with a /b) and if the OP wants to launch it after testing the first part, then that's ok too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that of course, but it involves searching for the file recursively in every folder of your hard drive partition(s).

Another way is to add the folder containing the .exe you want to execute in the PATH environment variable but it's **not recommended** to add every program you own to the PATH. (It's meant to remain quite small in size).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax of FIND command in dos.

http://www.computerhope.com/findhlp.htm

Answer (score 0):

taskmgr.exe can be executed from any path at the command prompt, because its location falls within the directories listed in the %PATH% variable.  You can potentially add any additional folders you would like to this variable to make any applications within follow the same behavior.  Caveat: Some applications do not run properly unless started from within their home directory.

Editing the %PATH% variable via the GUI varies between versions of Windows, or you can edit it from the command prompt.